# 504 error accessing Kinvey handshake(Rest api)

Tags: rest, libgdx, kinvey, http-status-code-504

I have been trying to get the Kinvey [handshake](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/getting-started#handshake) for the REST api to work for a while now but have not had any luck. I am using [libgdx's net class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html) to send the http request. Wverytime I send the request I get a 504(Gateway Timeout) error. I am following the instructions on the website so I am not sure why I would get that error.

Here is my attempt:

```
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET);
    request.setHeader("GET", "/appdata/:App_key");
    request.setHeader("Host:", "baas.kinvey.com");
    String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64Coder.encodeString("App_key:App_secret");
    request.setHeader("Authorization:", authHeader);
    request.setUrl("https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/App_key");
    System.out.println("HTTP REQUEST: " + request.getHeaders());
    responseListener listener = new responseListener() {
        public void handleHttpResponse (HttpResponse httpResponse) {

                HttpStatus status = httpResponse.getStatus();

                if (status.getStatusCode() >= 200 && status.getStatusCode() < 300) {
                    System.out.println("HTTP SUCCESS!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("HTTP ERROR: " + status.getStatusCode());
                }
                System.out.println("HTTP :" + httpResponse.getResultAsString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("REQUEST FAILED!" +t.getMessage());
            super.failed(t);
        }

    };

    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, listener);
```

As far as I can tell, there is something wrong with the header. I have tested the Url which takes me to a login screen. The login works after I put in the App key as the user name and the Master secret as the password. Is there something obviously wrong? Is there a way I can debug this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Kinvey and can help you out with this.

A couple things:

first, there are some extra headers there that you don't need.  While they might not be the cause of the issue, it is still safe to remove:

```
request.setHeader("GET", "/appdata/:App_key");
request.setHeader("Host:", "baas.kinvey.com");
```

Note that GET is set when you create the `HttpRequest`, and Host is set when you define the URL.

Second, get rid of the colon after "authorization" when setting your header, make it look like this:

```
request.setHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
```

Also, you mention that it works with your master secret but not with your app secret?  Can you ensure that you are base64 encoding both?

One last thing-- ensure that you replace `App_Key` with your actual app key, in the URL as well as in the headers.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the colons not the GET or host headers. Removing the colons from Authorization and Host fixed the problem.